# Relative next closest clock time unit with DateTime or strtotime

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I'm looking to get the next closest `next {clocktime unit}` from now using the format that goes into the DateTime constructor, or strtotime function.

Let me demo the problem. I'm trying to get the next closest 4pm.

Imagine it's 4:30 pm, the next closest 4pm should be tomorrow at 4pm.  For days, it's as simple as `next {day}`, so naturally I tried...

```
(new DateTime("next 4pm"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // invalid
(new DateTime("next 16:00"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // invalid
```

so, I moved onto this

```
(new DateTime(""))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
(new DateTime("4pm"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
(new DateTime("+8 hours"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
(new DateTime("+8 hours 4pm"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which produces this output:

```
string(19) "2020-06-10 16:47:10" // now
string(19) "2020-06-10 16:00:00" // 4pm
string(19) "2020-06-11 00:47:10" // +8 hours
string(19) "2020-06-11 00:00:00" // +8 hours 4pm ??
```

Where as I was expecting the `+8 hours 4pm` to output this:

```
string(19) "2020-06-11 16:00:00"
```

So I went off to the php docs, I found this [note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

> Relative statements are always processed after non-relative statements. This makes "+1 week july 2008" and "july 2008 +1 week" equivalent.
>
> Exceptions to this rule are: "yesterday", "midnight", "today", "noon" and "tomorrow". Note that "tomorrow 11:00" and "11:00 tomorrow" are different. Considering today's date of "July 23rd, 2008" the first one produces "2008-07-24 11:00" where as the second one produces "2008-07-24 00:00". The reason for this is that those five statements directly influence the current time.

So I've tried a few other things leveraging those exceptions but couldn't seem to get anything useful -- and so I tried looking around online and found plenty of people trying something similar, but nothing exactly like this.

And sure, it's possible with some additional processing but I'm interested in a pure 1 strtotime / DateTime solution. I'm wondering if I'm missing something simple or if it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Break up your relative time into two pieces:

1. Set it to eight hours from now
2. Set it to 4pm

```
echo (new DateTime("+8 hours"))->modify('4pm')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2020-06-11 16:00:00
```